# 1989 7.3 IDI wont start

Tags: ford, diesel

I have a 1987 F250 with a  1989 7.3 IDI swap, the truck always used to run great. I went outside to try and fire her up and she wont start. I've tried plugging in the block heater and using ether.  It still wont start up. Just put in new batteries so that isn't a  problem. Cranks over good with no hesitation and the wait to start light goes on for about 13-15 seconds.

Comment: So it's cranking or just turning? do you hear it trying to fire?

Comment: It fired up today, what are the odds, it wont fire up in the warm but she sure fires up in the cold lol, gave her a good shot of ether today and she fired up no problem.